# How to know a playlist is whether private or not through YouTube API not using OAuth

Tags: youtube-api

I'm running into a problem with status of a playlist. What I want to do is to get a playlist status **without OAuth**. But, it is only retrieved when I use [playlists.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list#try-it) with OAuth.

When I send a request about a private playlist with playlists.list using API_KEY, it responses with:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=id%2Csnippet%2Cstatus&id={PRIVATE_PLAYLIST_ID}&key={API_KEY}

{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistListResponse",
 "etag": "\"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/zJL80hJ0IwMo5wddECFapC8I6Q4\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

This doesn't give any clues the playlist is private or other status to me. If I figure it out through YouTube API, how should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [playlistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#try-it) instead of playlist.list.

It'll give kind of the indirect information. Even though it doesn't make sure a playlist is exactly private, I think it is useful just in case.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=status&playlistId={PRIVATE_PLAYLIST_ID}&key={API_KEY}

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.playlistItem",
    "reason": "playlistItemsNotAccessible",
    "message": "The request is not properly authorized to retrieve the specified playlist.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "playlistId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The request is not properly authorized to retrieve the specified playlist."
 }
}
```