# How can I figure the youtube video out whether it is private or not existed?

Tags: youtube-api

When I use `video.list` with API_KEY **(not authenticated with OAuth)** for a private or not existed (maybe deleted or invalid video id) video, I can't know status of the video at all. It just only gives empty items.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=foo&key={API_KEY}

{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/Rk41fm-2TD0VG1yv0-bkUvcBi9s\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 0
 },
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

[The document is telling me if I can't find video resource, you will get an error.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#errors) But, it doesn't happen to me whatever `id` is. I've found out [the solution in similar situation for Playlist case before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763477/how-to-know-a-playlist-is-whether-private-or-not-through-youtube-api-not-using-o), it was possible to catch the information to use `playlistItem.list` indirectly. However, in this situation, how can I find out the status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried it out myself. Returned with a response status of 200, message null and an empty JSON item object too. It's weird that this is handled for `playlistitems.list` but not for `video.list`. Google Developers might have missed out on handling these kinds of scenarios for `video.list`. Guess there's really no way of telling if a video is private or if it even did exist at all using the Youtube Data API.

What I thought of is to try to make requests directly to the Youtube URL using the url

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<id>
```

then just check at the contents of `<div class =”content”>`

You can try to do this by using [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) or any similar XML traversing tools.

Comment: It might be the best way in this trouble. I hope Google Developers take this on and resolve.